# Android Studio Git Error: Error updating changes: Line is too short. xStatus=[0], yStatus=[0]

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to integrate git into Android Studio Artic Fox and getting the following error after I enabled git -->  Clicked Add --> Commit.

```
Error: Error updating changes: Line is too short. xStatus=[0], yStatus=[0],
line=[starting fsmonitor-daemon in 'C:/users/pcuser/AndroidProjectFolders....
```

Anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the IDE you are using, in that it is getting output that is normal for Git, but thinking that this output is abnormal. Given that the fsmonitor daemon is long lived, it's *possible* that just retrying will get past the problem, but you should contact whoever sold you this defective software and have them fix it.

Comment: Ha!  It's Android Studio, and they didn't sell it to me LOL.  I'll look into it and test and see if there are other solutions out there.  Thank you.

Comment: Well, if it's freeware, it's probably up to you to fix it then :-)